# How to make an hourly time series in R with this data?

Tags: r, time-series, data-mining

```
times         booked_res
11:00         23
13:00         26
15:00         27
17:00         25
19:00         28
21:00         30
```

So I need to use the ts() function in R to convert this frame into a time series. The column on the right are the number of people reserved in each time. How should I approach this? I'm not sure about the arguments and I don't know if the frequency should be set to 24 (hours in a day) or 10 (11:00 to 21:00) as shown above. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Based way is to type `?ts` in command line of RStudio and look at examples.

Answer (score -1):

First, find the frequency by noting that you are taking a sample every two minutes. The frequency is the inverse of the time between samples, which is 1/2 samples per minute or 30 samples per hour. The data you're interested in is on the right, so you can just use that data vector rather than the entire data frame. The code to convert that into a time series is simply:

```
 booked_res <- c(23,26,27,25,28,30)
 ts(booked_res,frequency = 30)
```

A simple plot with your data might be coded like this:

```
plot(ts(booked_res,frequency = 30),ylab='Number of people reserved',xlab='Time (in hours) since start of sampling',main='Time series chart of people reservations')
```

**UPDATE:**

A time series model can only be created in R when the times series is *stationary*. Using a varying sample rate would make the time series *non-stationary*, and so you wouldn't be able to create a time-series object in R.

[This page on Analytics Vidhya](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/12/complete-tutorial-time-series-modeling/) provides a nice definition of stationary and non-stationary time series, while [this page on R bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/time-series-analysis-building-a-model-on-non-stationary-time-series/) gives some resources that relate to analyzing a non-stationary time series.

Comment: The thing is though, I'm not taking samples. The values on the right are people booking places for those times so it could be any number at any time, that 30 could and definitely will change.  Also, I thought the frequency value is based on that time column? I would also need to have the time for each number of bookings on the x axis